# Unit tests with CMake without duplicate compilation

Tags: c++, unit-testing, cmake

I'm trying to write unit tests for classes in a library. Building the lib and
the tests is done with CMake.

```
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── src
│   ├── Bar.cpp
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   └── Foo.cpp
└── test
    ├── BarTest.cpp
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    └── FooTest.cpp
```

The `src/CMakeLists.txt` is simply `add_library(Example Foo.cpp Bar.cpp)`.
And because I'd like to build the unit tests without building the library (i.e.
if I make a change to say `Foo` I can run its unit test without having the
interaction with `Bar` to work already. So the `test/CMakeLists.txt` looks like
this:

```
add_executable(FooTest FooTest.cpp ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/Foo.cpp)
add_test(bla::FooTest ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/FooTest)

add_executable(BarTest BarTest.cpp ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src/Bar.cpp)
add_test(bla::BarTest ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/BarTest)
```

However, this results in every source file being build twice:

```
[ 11%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/Example.dir/Foo.o
[ 22%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/Example.dir/Bar.o
[ 33%] Linking CXX static library libExample.a
[ 33%] Built target Example
[ 44%] Building CXX object test/CMakeFiles/FooTest.dir/FooTest.o
[ 55%] Building CXX object test/CMakeFiles/FooTest.dir/__/src/Foo.o
[ 66%] Linking CXX executable FooTest
[ 66%] Built target FooTest
[ 77%] Building CXX object test/CMakeFiles/BarTest.dir/BarTest.o
[ 88%] Building CXX object test/CMakeFiles/BarTest.dir/__/src/Bar.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable BarTest
[100%] Built target BarTest
```

Is it possible to avoid this? I.e. if I have build `src/Foo.cpp` before for a
unit test, don't build it again for a library? All flags are the same.

Comment: It's common to confirm that code builds before testing that it runs. Is it really so bad that  library, _Example_, gets built first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind the additional targets, that's what CMake's [object libraries](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html#object-libraries) are for:

```
add_library(Foo OBJECT Foo.cpp)
add_library(Bar OBJECT Bar.cpp)
add_executable(Example $<TARGET_OBJECTS:Foo> $<TARGET_OBJECTS:Bar>)
```

And then

```
add_executable(FooTest FooTest.cpp $<TARGET_OBJECTS:Foo>)
add_executable(BarTest BarTest.cpp $<TARGET_OBJECTS:Bar>)
```